# Memory space of arrays in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

What is memory space of arrays declared in kernel? For example in following code I declare array `a`. Where this array will be located? I'm confused between local memory and registers? If it is in registers then how exactly they are mapped?

```
__device__ int ptr=0;  

__global__ void a()  
{  
    int b[9][9];                                         
    atomicAdd(&ptr,1);  
    b[0][0]=ptr;                                       
    for(int i=1;i<9;i++)  
    {  
        for(int j=1;j<9;j++)  
        {  
            b[i][j]=b[i-1][j-1]+1;  
        }  
    }  
    ptr=b[7][7]+1;                                                 
}     

int main()  
{
    a<<<1,1>>>();  
    return 0;  
}
```

In general, is there any way to see memory space of each variable through `.ptx` files?
I compiled this with `--ptxas-options=-v` but no useful info. I looked `.o` files but it doesn't contain what i want. All I want is location of variables used in kernel.

Comment: Such an array is thread-local data and will therefore be stored in local memory by default. Depending on access pattern and size, and subject to compiler optimization, it _may_ be placed in registers. For the data to wind up in registers, all accesses must use compile-time constant indices, and the array must be "small", as determined by a compiler heuristic.

Comment: how to know the actual location of these allocations?

Comment: Look at the PTX (you can use --keep ro save the intermediate PTX). You will either see loads from local memory, or register accesses. On second thought, the allocation to register may also happen in the compiler backend which translated PTX to SASS machine code. You can examined the generated SASS with cuobjdump --dump-sass.

Comment: I was expecting some construct like `alloca()` in `.ptx` file but there is nothing like that. For above code, kernel portion contains only `.loc` debugger directive which is no way related to allocations.

Comment: @username_4567: If that is the real code you compiled, it shouldn't contain anything - the kernel contains no real code, and the compiler will emit a null stub for the kernel. Use a real example and the behaviour will be different.

Comment: Please look for new code which I compiled..

Comment: That is no different - compiler optimisation will elminiate all that code too. Make a global memory *write* depend on the local array, and then have a look at the resulting PTX

Comment: Yes there is a significant difference. I did one more experiment. I changed array size to 9*9 and compiled with `--maxrregcount=20` and I profiled application with NVVP and it shows 0% local mem overhead how is that possible? You can have look at new kernel I edited.

Comment: @username_4567: Your code of 2 hours ago still compiles to a null kernel. Please think these questions though a bit more before you ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Thread's private array definitely is stored at local memory space, in the DRAM off-the-chip, and maybe cached in memory hierarchy. Generally, non-array variable are considered as virtual registers in PTX and the number of registers in PTX are unlimited. However, obviously all these virtual registers are not mapped to physical registers. A PTX postprocessor spills some registers to local space according to the micro-architecture flags specified for NVCC, and optimizes the register usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question as I've got confirm view from one of the presentation in GTC. So, Compiler will try to put these arrays in registers if they are small enough. If they cannot accommodate in register file it will be spilled to local memory. But primary storage area is registers!!